# How to create json rectangle data from a Photoshop script

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a photoshop script that is cutting up layers of a PSD file into tiles (it's for a parallax game engine).  This works well, but now I want to be able to create regions (rectangles) in the PSD that can be detected by the script and exported as json data.

Can anyone suggest a good way in Photoshop to a) visually create this information in the PSD and b) the script that would write out this data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated - this would remove about 3 manual, error prone steps from our current process if we can solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just rectangles that will hold the data for you then that's easy. You can just create a layer with a unique name, select the area that you need the data for, fill that with a single colour - say bright orange or something that will stand out. So now you have a layer with your region data. In your script get the layer by name

```
app.documents.getByName("Data_for_Region_1");
```

...and then you can then export that layer's data (co-ordinates - presumably) as a JSON file with layer bounds.

```
 var x = parseFloat(app.activeDocument;.activeLayer.bounds[0])
 var y = parseFloat(app.activeDocument;.activeLayer.bounds[1])
 var x1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument;.activeLayer.bounds[2])
 var y1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument;.activeLayer.bounds[3])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as an answer because it will solve the problem. Ideally though I'd like to have multiple rectangles on each layer, simply because there will be a bunch of them. Thanks!